# The audience in ID Token [host.exp.Exponent] does not match the expected audience

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, apple-authentication

I am getting the error "[FirebaseError: Firebase: The audience in ID Token [host.exp.Exponent] does not match the expected audience. (auth/invalid-credential).]"

I am currently trying to set up Sign in with Apple on my expo application and have it connected to Firebase for user authentication. The service ID I created in my apple developer account as well as the service ID for Apple sign-in method on Firebase are the same.

I think I could figure this problem out very easily if I knew where the error message is getting [host.exp.Exponent] from. The bundle ID in my app.json is the same as the App ID (which is different from the service ID) from my apple developer account.

I've taken a look at the other issues with the same error out there, but none of the solutions have worked for me (service ID matches apple developer account and firebase, bundle ID in app.json matches app id in developer account)